# Проблема с сеткой css, float

Tags: css, float

Проблема заключается в непонятных размерах большого блока. Хотя, по подсчетам, он должен быть ровно в два раза больше, и, следовательно, под ним должно поместиться еще 2 маленьких блока.

Как его можно поставить в то же место? Флексами не разобрался, занимает целый ряд. При ресайзе окна он должен выталкивать левые блоки. http://new.navcav.com/

Comment: По поводу "под ним должно поместиться". Высота должна быть не 420px, а 416px, т.к. отступы у вас - по 8px.

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев это мне пришлось уже к этому прибегнуть, должно быть ровно 420 и 10px, но когда их ставишь - блок визуально становится больше, не знаете в чем причина? Весь день уже не могу придти к ответу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сетка в вашем примере рушится из-за `display: inline-block;` у слайдов.

Дело в том, что строчно-блочные (inline-block) элементы, при расположении их в ряд - пытаются вести себя как строчные (inline) - выстраиваться в соответствии с интерлиньяжем (line-height), размерами шрифта (font-size). И также, что важно в вашем случае - между ними может присутствовать небольшой зазор, равный ширине пробела при установленном размере шрифта. Он то и рушит сетку - зазоры между тайлами оказываются больше, чем вы задаете с помощью `margin`.

Проблему решает установка `display: block;` и `float: left;` для этих блоков:

```
.tile {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

`margin` можно вернуть к значению `10px`, и для мелких, и для большого тайла. Сетка не поедет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! То, что нужно. Когда ставит float: left, забыл, что изначально пытался выравнять inline-block'ами. Еще раз благодарю вас

Comment: ну как бы обычно при использовании инлайн блоков, сбрасывается размер шрифта у контейнера этих блоков в 0, а уже для самих блоков размер шрифта задается необходимый. Так избавляются от пробелов... Думаю Вам это известно.

Comment: @pepel_xD, да, техника известна. Она нестабильная (https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/#article-header-id-3) и приводит к излишнему разрастанию стилей для `font-size`. Поэтому не рекомендую ее использовать.

Comment: @ Виталий Емельянцев На мой взгляд не разрастание, более точный контроль над этим свойством. В большинстве случаев сбрасываю шрифт в 0 для всех тегов в таблице сбросов, далее для `body` назначаю размер по умолчанию в пикселях, а уже дальше по необходимости либо в `em`, либо в `%`... но это имхо... дело вкуса...